# Centering causes change in spacing

Tags: spacing, formatting, lyx

For some reason when I center the text on my page the spacing to go from single to double.  Using the latest LyX I have the following text written in standard.

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

When I change the paragraph alignment to center it looks like the following.

```
                                      Line 1

                                      Line 2

                                      Line 3

                                      Line 4
```

No other options are changed and the paragraph spacing and document spacing are set to single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is LyX doing things in a poor way. With the default settings, the LaTeX code generated by LyX looks like

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

Line 4
```

An empty line in the code signifies a paragraph break. However, when you select all the four paragraphs and change the alignment to centered, the code becomes

```
\begin{center}
Line 1
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
Line 2
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
Line 3
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
Line 4
\par\end{center}
```

Each `center` environment adds some vertical space before and after it, creating the appearance of double spaced lines. It would have been better if the code had looked like

```
\begin{center}
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

Line 4
\end{center}
```

I don't know there are ways of fixing this, other than using ERTs to insert `\begin{center}` before `Line 1` and `\end{center}` after `Line 4`, keeping the paragraph alignment to the default. Perhaps a bug report should be filed at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome

Comment: second the recommendation to file a bug report.